# Does Java has any standard mechanism for uudecoding?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime, uuencode, uudecode

I was writing a Java program to download attachments from POP3 email. Originally I do this with getting an input stream of a MimePart if its content type is validated. And then I can simply write the input stream into a local file through a FileOutputStream.

However, one thing I encountered is that, after I received an email with an attached file as its only content and access it, the mail (of type Message) only consists of a single part, which is of type text/plain. And its content consists of massive random-looking character.

After searching through the internet I found that the file is uuencoded. Then I tried to find if there is any standard library for decoding it but seems I ran out of luck. So I would like to know is there any standard/ usual ways to decode it and obtain the attached file? Thanks a lot.

Comment: AFAIK there's no official standard library to handle this. You may use one of the available libraries on the net to handle the work.

Comment: There is Apache Commons Codec but it has no UU codec...

Comment: For voters to close: the question is not asking for a library to handle this, but if there is a standard way to do it using Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the "[Java(TM) EE 7 Specification APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?overview-summary.html)" supports encoding and decoding with `uuencode`.

See [`MimeUtility.decode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#decode%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29):

> In addition, "uuencode" is also supported.

Comment: To be clear, that's part of JavaMail, which it sounds like you're already using.

Comment: @BillShannon: I was wondering the same thing. The title of the JavaDoc says it's part of J2EE 1.4, though. Maybe the Java Mail API was merged in J2EE?

Comment: @AaronDigulla JavaMail is part of EE but it is also standalone.